# Calendar button is not working on HP Zbook 14u G5

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, ubuntu-gnome, calendar, events

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 on HP Zbook 14u G5. F12 key on my keyboard has a calendar image on it. When I press this key on Windows, calendar starts. But on Ubuntu this feature is not working. First of all, I changed configuration file /lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb. Now, when i press F12, evtest shows that I'm pressing KEY_CALENDAR. But it still does not open calendar. Moreover, when I press F12, evtest outputs this:

```
Event: time 1668852816.960635, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 1d
Event: time 1668852816.960635, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 29 (KEY_LEFTCTRL), value 1
Event: time 1668852816.960635, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1668852816.960745, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 38
Event: time 1668852816.960745, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 56 (KEY_LEFTALT), value 1
Event: time 1668852816.960745, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1668852816.960901, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 64
Event: time 1668852816.960901, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 397 (KEY_CALENDAR), value 1
Event: time 1668852816.960901, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1668852817.021851, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 1d
Event: time 1668852817.021851, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 29 (KEY_LEFTCTRL), value 0
Event: time 1668852817.021851, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1668852817.021972, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 38
Event: time 1668852817.021972, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 56 (KEY_LEFTALT), value 0
Event: time 1668852817.021972, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1668852817.022102, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 64
Event: time 1668852817.022102, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 397 (KEY_CALENDAR), value 0
Event: time 1668852817.022102, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

But I don't actually press ctrl and alt keys on my keyboard.
Can someone please help me to figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. After editing configuration file /lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb I added a custom shortcut in gnome-settings. Now calendar when I press the calendar button everything works fine )